# removeClass doesn't work

Tags: click, removeclass

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slideToggle").click(function(e) {   
       e.preventDefault();
       $(".top-menu li").removeClass("active");
       var $more = $("#impressum").slideToggle("slow");
       $("body,html").animate({
           scrollTop: $more.offset().top
    }, {
        duration: 1100,
        queue: false
    })
    });
});
```

When I click the anchor with class slideToggle, it opens the imprint div.
So far so good.
But the event `$(".top-menu li").removeClass("active");` is not executed. I dunno why.
As soon as I remove the slideToggle function, the event from above works. But I can't combine both events on  the click function.

Can you help?
Thanks in advance!

edit: 
It seems like the script is colliding with another script I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.anchorLink").anchorAnimate()
// Cache selectors
var topMenu = $(".top-menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a.anchorLink"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
   // Set/remove active class
   menuItems
     .parent().removeClass("active")
     .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
});
});
```

Because if I delete this script, the other script does work.
Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

First what will the variable `var $more =` do?
I think this is superfluous to this function, this variable is never user anywhere.

Maybe you can post the whole code.

Grtz,
Wouter

Answer (score 0):

What version of jquery are you using?
I made a Fiddle and your code works (I'm watching the li element with firebug and the class "active" dissapears correctly)

http://jsfiddle.net/FKxyT/2/

You can try changing `removeClass`for `toggleClass`. Maybe that works.

Comment: I've updated my first post. I think I found the mistake but I don't know how to get both scripts working.